# session is lost when i use window.open in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, session

I'm using window.open to open a new window and this is my code sample

```
var path = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
var page = path+"/jsp/displayCompareResult.jsp";
window.open(page, 'displayCompareResult','');
```

This works absolutely fine in IE8, but in IE9 window.open gets created in new session.
My application runs only on IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

It happened in my chrome also.I solved this by adding

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../img/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

If "new session" means that IE is opening your window to the new tab, your have to change this setting. It is found in IE Settings General-tab (the leftmost tab) and above the last field there is a field called Tabs (or sth). Click Settings-button in this field, and in opened window you can find a field called Pop-up windows. Pick "Open pop-up windows in new window" and save settings.

Comment: no. this didnt work.
after new window is opened, if i try to access the values from session i'm gettin it as null.
this happens only in ie9